# Why is a tonsillectomy (tonsil-removal) typically more painful the older you are? Are the the pain nerves more advanced?

Tags: pain, nerves, age, tonsil-tonsillectomy

I had my tonsils removed in my mid twenties, and my doctors told me that it was going to be a lot more painful than if I had done it when I was just a lad. They were certainly correct!!

Why is it that a tonsillectomy is more painful to have as an adult? Are the pain nerves more mature? Or is it that the tonsil is larger than when I was a child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After removal of tonsils, most adults
>   have significant pain for 10 -14 days, some up to 3 weeks. **Because 
>   adults & teenagers have larger tonsils and more developed throat muscles**, pain and muscle spasm can 
>   make it difficult to swallow for 2 weeks or more.  Constipation may occur because narcotic pain 
>   medication, when taken regularly, can slow down the bowels.  [link](http://communityent.com/post-op/adult-tonsil.pdf)